# pre set value for dropdown in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a drop down to select countries from a back-end API call.

code:

```
this.http.get(SERVER_URL+"/edit/getAllCountry")
    .subscribe((res) => {
        this.countries = res;
    });
```

this will returns me list of countries from my database.

ill be printing them in html like:

**billingPage.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="country" (ngModelChange)="countryChanged(country)" >
                            <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue] = 'c'> {{c.countryName}} </option>
                        </select>
```

the question is , before coming to this **billing.html** page I have a selected value for the country. for example I have selected '**USA**' and how can I load it in into to the dropdown when the page is loaded.

in the dropdown list '**USA**' should be selected when the page loads.

Comment: no I need to display the country parsed from previous controller in the billing.html page dropdown list.

Comment: The idea is the same. The default value on the next page is the one selected. It's set in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**Ts**

```
 selectedcountry:any;

 this.selectedcountry="USA";
 this.http.get(SERVER_URL+"/edit/getAllCountry")
.subscribe((res) => {
    this.countries = res;        
});
```

it is custom example .Once we selected and save into DB means, call another API which we saved the values, like below example:

```
 this.http.get(SERVER_URL+"/edit/getselectedCountry")
.subscribe((data) => {
    this.selectedcountry = data;        
});
```

**billingPage.html**

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedcountry"  >
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [selected]="selectedcountry==c.countryName" value="{{c.countryName}}"> {{c.countryName}}
  </option>
```

Comment: works perfectly ty :)